# how to write a backward function for a caffe python layer with two top blobs?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, gradient-descent, pycaffe

After installing caffe on ubuntu 16.04. I trained cifar10-quick model successfully, then I added a simple python layer as follow:

```
import caffe
import numpy as np

class My_Custom_Layer(caffe.Layer):  
    def setup(self, bottom, top):
        if len(bottom) != 1:
            raise Exception("Wrong number of bottom blobs")  

    def forward(self, bottom, top):
        top[0].data[...] = bottom[0].data

    def reshape(self, bottom, top):
        top[0].reshape(*bottom[0].shape)        

    def backward(self, top, propagate_down, bottom):
        bottom[0].diff[...] = top[0].diff
```

now I want to add another top blob, top[1] with some changes in bottom[0], but I have no idea how to change backward function!